# PHP header and $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, redirect, header

I'm currently building a CMS and I'm having an issue with PHP sessions:

- Anywhere on my website user can start CMS by adding query string to URL -> ?mod=admin
- ?mod=admin will redirect to login.php
- After authentication I would like to redirect user to page he came from with CMS functionalities enabled

For that I store current page url in a session before user go to login.php

**url.class.php script**

```
function curPageURL() {
 session_start();
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
 }
 $_SESSION['url'] = $pageURL;
}
```

**Login.php script:**
if validation successful I start a session and TRY to redirect user to page he came from:

```
if($num_rows == 1){
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['username'];
  header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['url']);
}
```

I get a "session had already started" error.
But if I redirect to a specific page (homepage for instance) then all is working fine.
for instance -> header('Location: index.php');

Comment: and what is the line '$_SESSION['username'];' supposed to do?

Comment: If $_SESSION['username'] exist then I know user is logged in

Comment: in that case you have to put an 
`if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){ } `
around the header instead of that line. The redirect should work though, if the url is correct and you don't output any html before the header statement.

Comment: you know you have to use session_start() also in the function curPageURL?

Comment: Before if($num_rows == 1){} I do a login validation. I check that $_POST['username'] & $_POST['password'] = MySQL entries). If it returns a row then I log my user by starting a session on the page they will be redirected -> session_start(); $_SESSION['username'];

Comment: Your 'else' clause has a typo: `$_SERVER["PHP_SEFL"]` - should be PHP_SELF

Answer (score 2):

If thats the error you are getting then you need to check to see if you've already started the session somewhere else. In which case you need to put:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```

In place of where you put your normal session_start().

Comment: That might actually be the solution (unfortunately I cannot do a test right now). url.class.php is included in every pages so a session is already started.

Comment: Good, I had the same issue once before. You can only create a session once per page. I hope it does work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just redirect to the previous page using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?

What actually happens when you try to run your script in it's current state?

Comment: then chances are you have session_start() declared elsewhere in your code and this has been executed prior to the declaration here. Comment out session_start() and see what happens. Also as somebody else mentioned $_SESSION['username'] needs to be contained in an if statement to actually do something.

Comment: http_referer is not always available, and may not be the page from which the user came. it's user-provide data and can contain literally anything.

Comment: Good call Marc, referer headers can be disabled in the browser.

Comment: Every page of the site contains url.class.php (which saves current page url). So yes a session_start() is already declared. Does it mean that by removing "session_start();" from login.php function, session is still active and $_SESSION['username'] will be created?

Comment: In theory yes, as long as session_start() has been called somewhere in the stack the session will be initialised. If in doubt comment things out and see how it affects it, best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

In url.class.php, has you already started the session? Your problem could be that you haven't started the session, and hence no session data can be stored.

In your url.class.php try checking that the session variables hold the values that you want.

Comment: I amended my post - yes I started the session in url.class.php - that's why I'm getting an error when doing -> header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['url']);

Answer (score 0):

> Anywhere on my website user can start CMS

I assume you mean that the website is implemented via a CMS and that the user can gain access to elevated privileges / additional functionality at any stage by appending to the query string.

> store current page url in a session

Erk.

This is not the right place to store this information - it should be passed via the URL (or via POST - but that's not going to work across redirection):

```
session_start();
if (!is_auth_for_cms() && $_GET['mod']=='admin') {
     // simplified a bit...
     $comeback='http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
     // rewriting the get trigger avoids short circuit looping problems
     $comeback=urlencode(str_replace('mod=admin', 'mod=auth', $comeback));
     header("Location: " 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/login.php?backto=$comeback";
}
```

Leaving aside the typos in your code, what is the question?

```
if($num_rows == 1){
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['username'];
  header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['url']);
}
```

What do you think the third line does?

Comment: Apologies - my question has been removed by mistake. Just edited my original post.